# Unable to send front end form values to backend api in react, expressjs app?

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, mern

I am unable to save the data from react form , but in backend I am able to save only mongoose auto generated ID. This API is not saving email and password in database. When I do console log in server it is showing empty object. request body is giving empty object.

My express api route :

```
 app.post ('/contact', (req, res) => {
      const { email,password } = req.body;
      const contact = new Contact({
       email,
       password, 
      });
      console.log(req.body);
      contact.save();
      res.send(contact); 
    } )
```

In front end,  in browser developer console I can get the [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRLWe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For post data, you will need `body-parser`

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

More details here http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: I already added body-parser , that is not the issue

Comment: then it probably will need `var formidable = require('express-formidable');` instead?